# How do you use SearchResult for join fields using Map/Reduce Script?

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm starting to understand the Map/Reduce framework more and more for SuiteScript 2.0. However, all the help and SuiteAnswer articles show direct field relationships from the searchResult object.

How do you return a joined field as a Object Value during the map stage?

Example:

```
{"recordType":"manufacturingoperationtask","id":"1974","values":{"item.workOrder":{"value":"1517","text":"Agent Orange Pale Ale : AOP 1/2"},"enddate":"10/13/2017","formulanumeric":"65"}}
```

In this SearchResult object, I am trying to return the 1517 item internal id but haven't found a way to get it because the key is "item.workOrder".

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you just want to parse out the JSON string above, then it would be

```
var data = JSON.parse(result);
var workOrderId = data["item.workOrder"].value;
```

However, the typical way of accomplishing this through SuiteScript would be to use the Search `Result` Object's `getValue` method, along with its `join` option.

```
var workOrderId = result.getValue({
    name: "workOrder",
    join: "item"
});
```

FWIW I've written a whole [series of example-driven cookbooks](https://stoic.software/cookbooks/) to help you master Searching in SuiteScript.